# While calling simplify in sympy getting error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

When my python code tried to use simplify it shows following error. This problem showed after i run separate code file of pyparsing(Which execute successfully). The same  code is working fine before.
**Edit:**

```
>>> expression="a+b+z"
>>> t=simplify(expression)
ast.py:4: SyntaxWarning: invalid pattern (**) passed to Regex
  operator = pp.Regex("**").setName("operator")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\simplify\simplify.py", line 507, in simplify
    expr = sympify(expr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 308, in sympify
    from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (parse_expr, TokenError,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 11, in <module>
    import ast
  File "ast.py", line 4, in <module>
    operator = pp.Regex("**").setName("operator")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1920, in __init__
    self.re = re.compile(self.pattern, self.flags)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Please suggest?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a local file, `ast.py`, which is getting imported in place of Python's built-in [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).  You should remove or rename this file to avoid the name conflict, as this can cause other modules to not work correctly.

Additionally, your local module contains the following line, which is causing an exception on import:

```
operator = pp.Regex("**").setName("operator")
```

`**` is not a valid [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).  In a regular expression, `*` means "0 or more repetitions of the preceding expression", which doesn't make sense at the beginning of an expression because there is "nothing to repeat" (as the error message says).